# JavaMail file attachment in non-latin not displayed properly

Tags: java, email, encoding, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail (version 1.5) in a web application.

Users upload files via an `file` `input` element on an `html` form.

I then send the file via email. I use the same name as the file that was attached via the form (ie: I don't give it some custom name).

Some users upload files with non-latin file names.

According to docs I understand that no special encoding/decoding is needed with JavaMail unless I'm manipulating raw headers. Therefore I set the file name of the attachment via `mimeBodyPart.setFileName(fileName)` without encoding the file name.

However, this results in the file name showing up as question marks or underscores in the received email.
Testing printing `fileName` to the console or to a System folder displays the file name correctly.

**Things I've tried**

1. I tried setting "mail.mime.encodefilename", and "mail.mime.decodefilename" to true in the app's `ServletContextListener`.
2. I tried using the `MimeUtility` method `encodeText(text,charset, encoding)`.

*This worked and displayed the file name correctly but occasionally it would completely garble the file name: rather than question marks or underscores, it would garble the entire file name to look something like
"=_UTF-8_B_16rXqNeS15XXnSDXnNeg15zXlCAt157XmdeV157XoNeV16og15___ ___filename_1=__4..."*

*I did extensive testing to try to figure out what caused this garbling but couldn't get consistent results (tested for browsers and file name length). I suspect something was getting cached during testing because the results weren't consistent.*

3. I tried getting the file name both from the `Java` `Part` method `getSubmittedFileName()` and via a js script.

Any suggestions?

**Sample headers:**

> Content-Type: application/x-any;
>   name="=?UTF-8?B?16TXlCDXoteV15Mg157Xmdec15nXnSDXnA==?= =?UTF-8?B?1\";
>   name*1=\"5DXqNeV15og157Xodek16guZG9jeA==?=" Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   base64 Content-Disposition: attachment;
>   filename="=?UTF-8?B?16TXlCDXoteV15Mg157Xmdec15nXnSDXnA==?=
>   =?UTF-8?B?1\"; filename*1=\"5DXqNeV15og157Xodek16guZG9jeA==?="

Clients used to view received emails: Gmail website, Microsoft Outlook.

Comment: Try [JavaMail 1.6](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/), if you can.  Without the workarounds you described, what do the MIME headers for the file body part look like?  What mailers are you using to display the message and the file name?

Comment: Attached the things you requested. Are those the headers you meant?

Comment: Update: Javamail 1.6 did not fix the issue. I also tried 1.6 with setting the encodeFileName System property and that didn't work either.

Comment: I assume there were some newlines in the original message that got lost when you pasted the headers above.  But a bigger issue is that you have attributes such as `name="=?UTF-8?B?16TXlCDXoteV15Mg157Xmdec15nXnSDXnA==?= =?UTF-8?B?1\"; name*1=\"5DXqNeV15og157Xodek16guZG9jeA==?="` that should be two separate attributes: `name*0="=?UTF-8?B?16TXlCDXoteV15Mg157Xmdec15nXnSDXnA==?= =?UTF-8?B?1"; name*1="5DXqNeV15og157Xodek16guZG9jeA==?="`  Are those the headers before you sent the message, or the headers as received?

Comment: The second form, where the attribute value is split between two attributes, is defined by RFC 2231.  Some mailers don't support that form.  Perhaps your message passed through some mail server or gateway or anti-virus product that rewrote the headers into the incorrect form that you're seeing?  If you set the System property [`mail.mime.encodeparameters`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.encodeparameters) to false, the parameter value won't be split using the RFC 2231 form.  Try that and see if it works better.

Comment: Hey, regarding your first question: the headers posted in my question are after the message is received. I don't quite understand your corrected header description. The only difference is that you have `name*0` instead of `name`, correct? Both your code and my code define 2 attributes. I will look into how to define separate attributes and get back to you here. Regarding your second comment, I have tried messing with that property in the past but nothing changed.

Comment: JavaMail automatically splits the single file name attribute into name*0 and name*1 if the name is too long.  The receiving mail reader will combine name*0 and name*1 to reconstruct the long file name.  All of this depends on support for RFC 2231.  If setting `mail.mime.encodeparameters` to false doesn't change that, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and able to resolve it with `java-mail-api-1.6`. It doesn't seems standard but it can be useful if you facing such issues.

The other options like using:

`attachment.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(FileName, "UTF-8", null));`

was not performing well with different mail servers; results were random and confusing.

Below are steps that I used:

Step 1: Set following properties:

```
props.put("mail.mime.encodefilename", "true");
props.put("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");
```

Step 2: Set file name with:

```
attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; 
name=\""+FileName+"\"");
attachment.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
filename=\""+FileName+"\"");
```

Then remove other filename setting statements like

```
attachment.setFileName(FileName);
```